# What font in which the name of the author is printed by the documentclass "aomart"?

Tags: fonts

The "aomart" documentclass takes the form

```
\documentclass[manuscript]{aomart}
\newcommand{\ntt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}





\title[]{Test}
\author[]{Wissenschaft}
\email{}
\address{}




\begin{document}

\maketitle





\end{document}
\end{input}
```

I would like to know the font in which the name of the author is printed. I have suspected the "ttfamily" but found that "ttfamily" does not give the desired font.

Comment: It's Computer Modern Roman in small caps (`\scshape`)

Comment: @karlkoeller: Ah! Thanks so much. Is it the default font in the article documentclass? If not, would you please tell me which package to use?

Comment: If you would like to make it an answer, I am going to accept it. Thanks very much, I have found that how to call the font out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply Computer Modern Roman in small caps.

If you want to use it in your document use either the form `{\scshape text}` or `\textsc{text}`.